# How to share the same type definition in two files

Tags: flowtype

I can't figure out how to share a type definition in two files. Consider:

```
// /file_a.js

export const randomVariable: MySharedType = {thing: true};

// /file_b.js

export const anotherRandomVariable: MySharedType = {thing: false};
```

Both files use the `MySharedType` type so I want to move that type declaration to some shared types definition.

So I made a new directory for it and pointed to it under the `[libs]` section of my `flowconfig`. So the result is that I have:

```
// in /flow/typeExtensions/SharedTypes.js

// @flow
export type MySharedType = {thing: boolean}
```

However, flow doesn't want to play nice and still gives me errors:

```
 2:     export const randomVariable: MySharedType = {thing: true}
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ identifier `MySharedType`. Could not resolve name
```

I can't find any documentation or examples of how to create global shared flowtype definitions.

Here is a tiny repo that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/EvNaverniouk/shared-flow-types

Please help.

Comment: Do you specifically want it to be exposed it globally in your whole app? That is what `[libs]` does. You can make a normal JS file and `import type {MySharedType} from "./MySharedType.js"`.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be global in my whole app because it's going to be used in 50+ files and importing the type into each one is going to be frustrating.

Comment: I just did exactly what you described in your question and the type alias was available as expected. You'll have to include a more complete example. In particular it might be helpful if you included the contents of your `.flowconfig`. Also make sure that your version of Flow is up to date (v0.42.0 is the most recent version).

Comment: @NatMote I've created a tiny reproducible test case here: https://github.com/EvNaverniouk/shared-flow-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that Flow doesn't recognize changes to global [lib] files. So the solution was simply to restart the flow server:

`./node_modules/.bin/flow stop
./node_modules/.bin/flow start`

And now the shared types work fine. *facepalm*

Comment: This answer should be shouted from the mountaintops. Stumbled through this for over an hour, and this was an instant fix!

Answer (score 1):

I find that it is easier to import and export types like regular javascript functions and classes. So something like this:

**file_a.js**

```
// @flow
export type MySharedType = {thing: boolean}
export const randomVariable: MySharedType = MySharedType;
```

**file_b.js**

```
import type { MySharedType } from 'file_b';
export const anotherRandomVariable: MySharedType = {thing: false};
```

This way you can keep your type definitions close to the code that they belong to (e.g. PropTypes for a React component can be exported from the same file as the component itself) or you can make "type libraries", that is, define all you types in separate javascript files and import them from your regular code.

Comment: OP has explicitly said that they do not want to import this type into each file explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, this method is what I use when I need to share a type between 1 or 2 files. It works great, is clean and makes it easy to see where the types are coming from. 

However sometimes it's not logical where the type should be. Why is it in file_a? Why file_a and not file_b? They both have equal ownership/use of that type.

Also, from time to time, I have some types that are going to be used in 50+ files in my app. Having to import those types individually is a massive pain so I'm looking for something that allows me to define types globally in my whole application.

Comment: The equal ownership case is where I create a separate file that only exports types. Then both file_a and file_b can import from there